# Trouble using created function in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've made a SQL function. This is a simple function which gets IDs of given Gateway and Category objects by name:

```
USE [dev_ticketsystem]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetGatewayCategoryPair(@GatewayName varchar(100), @CategoryName varchar(100))

RETURNS @PairedTable TABLE 
(
    GatewayId uniqueidentifier,
    CategoryId uniqueidentifier
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CategoryId uniqueidentifier;
    DECLARE @GatewayId uniqueidentifier;

    SELECT @CategoryId = [Id] 
    FROM [dev_ticketsystem].[dbo].[Category]
    WHERE [Name] = @CategoryName;


    SELECT @GatewayId = [Id] 
    FROM [dev_ticketsystem].[dbo].[Gateway]
    WHERE [Name] = @GatewayName;

    IF @GatewayId IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        IF @CategoryId IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT @PairedTable
            SELECT @GatewayId, @CategoryId;
        END;
    END;
    RETURN;
END;
GO
```

After executing this script it created the function, so I can see in MS SQL Management Studio.

But when I'm trying to call it with :

```
USE [dev_ticketsystem]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CategoryGateway]
           ([GatewayId]
           ,[CategoryId])
     VALUES
           (dbo.GetGatewayCategoryPair('GateName', 'CatName').GatewayId,
           dbo.GetGatewayCategoryPair('GateName', 'CatName').CategoryId);
```

It throws exception :

```
Incorrect syntax near 'GetGatewayCategoryPair'.
```

How could this be fixed?

Comment: Insert into CategoryGateWay (GatewayId, CategoryId) SELECT  GatewayId, CategoryIdfROM dbo.GetGatewayCategoryPair('GateName', 'CatName')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the function to return a table.  Hence, you need to refer to it in the `FROM` clause:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CategoryGateway(GatewayId, CategoryId)
     SELECT gcp.GatewayId, gcp.CategoryId
     FROM dbo.GetGatewayCategoryPair('GateName', 'CatName') gcp;
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would move away from a Multi-statement table value function; they can be very slow. Use a inline table-value function. Which should look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetGatewayCategoryPair_itvf (@GatewayName varchar(100), @CategoryName varchar(100))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    SELECT G.ID AS GatewayId,
           C.ID AS CategoryId
    FROM (SELECT [Id] 
          FROM [dev_ticketsystem].[dbo].[Category]
          WHERE [Name] = @CategoryName) C
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT [Id] 
                 FROM [dev_ticketsystem].[dbo].[Gateway]
                 WHERE [Name] = @GatewayName) G
   WHERE C.ID IS NOT NULL
     AND G.ID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll test this too.